# Why is Select not Recognized as a Valid Method of XElement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

Based on the code I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703252/parsing-xml-string-in-c-sharp), my almost-identical code should work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stringifiedXML);
var Platypi = doc.Descendants("Platypus").Select(delItem => new
{
    Name = delItem.Element("duckbillName").Value,
    Length = delItem.Element("length").Value,
    Weight = delItem.Element("weight").Value,
    Age = delItem.Element("age").Value,
}).ToList();
```

Yet instead it violently jerks the rug from under my lazyboy and spills me on the floor, mocking my discomfiture with, "*'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

The question asked may rightly be responded to affirmatively, but right-clicking "Select" does not afford a "Resolve" context menu item, so I don't know what, if anything, I might be missing.

Comment: are you sure you have added a reference to `System.Linq` from your project?

Comment: I have System.XML.LINQ; I see no System.LINQ available...

Comment: what version of .NET Framework you are using? you need to use 4.0 version at least, in order to be able to use LINQ  methods

Comment: I'm using 4.5.1 in VS 2013

Comment: so, what did you get when you type `using System.Linq` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the  `System.Linq` namespace with:

```
using System.Linq;
```

All `LINQ` extension methods defined in the `Enumerable` class which is under the `System.Linq` namespace.If you are using `.NET Framework 4.5.1` version then you should be able to use `LINQ` methods after you add your reference.

Comment: Yes, that did it; I find it odd, or even a bug, that right-clicking "Select" does not afford a "Resolve" context menu item. If you don't know about yourself (.NET), how am I supposed to know about you? After all, I'm not a psychiatrist.

Comment: That is not adding a reference.  You are merely importing the names of types from other namespaces.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you are absouletly right.I updated my answer.This is just importing the namespace,a reference to `System.Core.dll` is necessary which is already added by default

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the System.Linq - namespace to use the Select extension method.
Select Add Reference and add the System.Core.dll to your project